# IBM watson rank and retrieve training the ranker getting Value error: No JSON could be decoded

Tags: ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I am trying to use the IBM Watson Rank and Retrieve service and I am following the tutorial with the sample data present in the portal i.e cranfield-data. However when I am trying to train the ranker using train.py I am getting the following error:

note: 1) I have uploaded the required JSON files
2) I am running the code in python2 environment.

Any help?

[image: Value Error: No JSON object could be decoded]

Answer (score 0):

Which file from the tutorial are you passing in as the `-i {relevance_file}` parameter? Is it this one: https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/doc-tutorial-downloads/retrieve-and-rank/cranfield-gt.csv?

Other things to check:

- The collection was created properly when you uploaded the https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/doc-tutorial-downloads/retrieve-and-rank/cranfield-data.json ([a search](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/?curl#query_standard) with the query `q=*:*` should yield 1400 results)
- The train.py file wasn't modified after download from https://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/doc-tutorial-downloads/retrieve-and-rank/train.py